# Add normal String or Integer

Tags: mongodb

In a aggregate I have a `group`-clause:

```
      {  $group: {
                _id: { town_id: "$_id.town" },
                houses_data: { $push:

                     { house_id: "$_id.house_id",
                       price: {
                           $divide: ["$sum", "$total"]
                             }
                      }
                }
             }
       }
```

**Like this everthing works fine**

But then I tried to add an extra field `description` in the `houses_data`:

```
    { house_id: "$_id.house_id",
      price: {
         $divide: ["$sum", "$total"]
      },
      description: "thats a house"
     }
```

**Now I get an error:**

```
FieldPath '2' doesn't start with $"
```

**But** Description is not a Field.
I want to add Description as a static String Value.
So in each `house_data`-array, there should be the same description.

**The output should look like:**

```
{town_id: 13, houses_data: [
   {house_id: 5, price: 32, description: "thats a house"},
   {house_id: 2, price: 12, description: "thats a house"}
   ]
 }
```

What do I wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**$literal**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator, in your `group` clause, as in:

```
{.. description: {$literal:"thats a house"} ..}
```

> FieldPath '2' doesn't start with $

indicates that the value is parsed as an `expression`. The `$literal` operator tells `mongoDB` - to not parse the content as an `expression`.

> Returns a value without parsing. Use for values that the aggregation
>   pipeline may interpret as an expression.

**Note**: That the syntax for the `$group` stage operator, is as follows:

```
{ $group: { _id: <expression>, 
            <field1>: { <accumulator1> : <expression1> }, ... } }
```

`$literal` is not one of the [accumulators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) and cannot be used in place of an accumulator, but needs to be a part of the `expression`.

Answer (score 2):

[***$literal***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#literal-aggregation) is what you are looking for. However I don't believe it's  valid for the group stage of `aggregation`. I've just tried it and couldn't get it to work.

So instead I would suggest adding in the description field prior to the group operation of the pipeline and then retaining it in the group stage using [***$first***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#first-aggregation) expression:

```
 { $project: { 
              _id: 1, 
              sum: 1, 
              total: 1, 
              description: { $literal: "thats a house" } 
              }
 },
 {  $group: {
            _id: { town_id: "$_id.town" },
            houses_data: { $push:

                 { house_id: "$_id.house_id",
                   price: {
                       $divide: ["$sum", "$total"]
                         },
                   description: { $first: "$description" }
                  }
            }
         }
   }
```

I've tested something similar and it works.

Comment: It is perfectly correct to use `$literal` in a group clause. It just needs to be enclosed by one of the `$group` operators such as `$push`.

Comment: I hadn't realised that. Thanks for the correction. If you add that to your example I'd be more than happy to up vote it as the better answer as it would clarify for all.